# RDP, prevent certain shortcuts from being passed to remote?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Remote computer has only one desktop. Local Windows 10 computer has two desktops. When I press Ctrl+Win+->, I want to switch my local desktop. But it seems the key combination is passed to the remote computer, which in turn does nothing.

Can I prevent certain shortcuts (such as Ctrl+Win+->) from being passed to remote?

Comment: Are you running the RDP in full screen mode?

Comment: Yes. On OS X, I can use swipe left/right (trackpad) to see the local desktop. On Windows, I have to minimise RDP screen and go to the other desktop, and then go back to the desktop and restore RDP. So I was wondering if there is a quicker way to switch between remote/local desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is configure RDP setting (mstsc) to send the keyboard shortcuts to local computer OR Use RDP with "Smart Sizing"

*To Send windows keyboard Shortcuts to Local Computer:*

> Open mstsc > click on "Show Options" button > Switch to "Local Resources" tab > Change "Apply Windows Key Combinations" to "On this computer"

But this will push all the windows keyboard shortcuts to local computer, even <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: I think that option would be the best I could get.